# hi! i got problem in jquery function $(this).childen().val()

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

first my html and js&jquery

```js
(function($) {
    
    $('.list-group li').click(function(){
        console.log("push li");
        console.log($(this).attr('class'));
        console.log($(this).children('.hidden_input').val());
    });
    
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<ul class="list-group" id="serachList">     
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <div class="media align-items-lg-center flex-column flex-lg-row p-3">
      <div class="media-body order-2 order-lg-1">
        <h5 class="mt-0 font-weight-bold mb-2">card 1</h5> 
        <input class="hidden_input" type="hidden" id="hospitalId" value="1">               
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <div class="media align-items-lg-center flex-column flex-lg-row p-3">
      <div class="media-body order-2 order-lg-1">
        <h5 class="mt-0 font-weight-bold mb-2">card 2</h5> 
        <input class="hidden_input" type="hidden" id="hospitalId" value="1">               
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

when i click li,return exactly right answer (class of li)
but console.log($(this).children('.hidden_input').val()); is return undefined!
how can i get this.children.val?

this code is for free board with infinity scroll(card style)

Comment: i solved. I use 'find()' instead of 'children()'. I'm embarrassed because it's too noob. Thank you for reading the my question and scold me lol.

Answer (score 1):

You are only looking at "direct" children. Use `.find()` instead of `.children()`.

SEE: https://api.jquery.com/children/

> The .children() method differs from .find() in that .children() only travels a single level down the DOM tree while .find() can traverse down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren, etc.) as well.

```js
(function($) {
    
    $('.list-group li').click(function(){
        console.log("push li");
        console.log($(this).attr('class'));
        console.log($(this).find('.hidden_input').val());
    });
    
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-group" id="serachList">     
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <div class="media align-items-lg-center flex-column flex-lg-row p-3">
      <div class="media-body order-2 order-lg-1">
        <h5 class="mt-0 font-weight-bold mb-2">card 1</h5> 
        <input class="hidden_input" type="hidden" id="hospitalId" value="1">               
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <div class="media align-items-lg-center flex-column flex-lg-row p-3">
      <div class="media-body order-2 order-lg-1">
        <h5 class="mt-0 font-weight-bold mb-2">card 2</h5> 
        <input class="hidden_input" type="hidden" id="hospitalId" value="2">               
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you!